# Three.js camera movement after html button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm trying to create a simple animation using [three.js](https://threejs.org/), HTML, and CSS. My idea was to place multiple [BoxGeometries](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) created in a for loop and adjust the rotation of each box a little bit more than the last each iteration, which I have successfully created.

Here is my main.js file:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';


//Initialize Camera and Set Position
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
camera.position.setZ(0);
camera.position.setX(32);
camera.position.setY(0);

//Create Scene0
const scene = new THREE.Scene();


//Initialize Renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true} );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


//Initialize OrbitControls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


//Initialize Light
const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xfffff, 1);
pointLight.position.set( 1000, 1000, 1000);
scene.add(pointLight);

//Intro cube init
//This is the for loop that creates multiple Box meshs that rotate a little more than the last 
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: false} );
for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  cube.position.x = i * 2
  cube.rotation.x = i * .05
  cube.scale.x = .1
  scene.add( cube );
}

//This is the even listenter for the HTML button
//Once "begin-animation" button is clicked, I want the function "startButton" to be called
var start_button = document.getElementById("begin-animation");
start_button.addEventListener("click", startButton);
function startButton(){
  camera.position.x -= 5;
}


// animation
function animation() {

  //I want the animation of the line below, but when the HTML button is clicked, not on start
  //camera.position.x -= 5;

  controls.update()
  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>

    <div class="container">
      <button id="begin-animation" class="begin-animation" value="False">Begin</button>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my style.css file:

```
canvas {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 8s ease infinite;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}



/* Container */
.container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
/* End Container */


/* Start Journey button */
.begin-animation {
    position: relative;

    border: transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;

    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradientButton 8s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes gradientButton {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}

/* End Journey button


/* Headers */
h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem #7DF9FF;
}
.subheading {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem #7DF9FF;
}
/* End Headers */


/* Spacer */
.spacer {
    height: 1500px;
}
```

In the `startButton()` function, you'll notice that I placed the `camera.position.x` call (which only moves the camera one position per button click) if the `id="begin-animation` button is clicked. This poses a problem for me because I want the begin button to be clicked only once - to start the animation.

If I move `camera.position.x` into the main `animation()` function, I get the result of the camera moving in a straight line that I want, but since it's in the main function, it runs before the start button is clicked.

How can I get the same result of having `camera.position.x` inside the main `animation()` function but only when the HTML button `id="begin-animation` is clicked once?

Here is an image about what I want (**note**: where the star is, or the initial camera position, is facing the first mesh so you only see a square. I moved the camera so you can see the full view of every mesh):
[image: animation guide]

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED BY @PhilN, SEE BELOW**

the problem you are facing is so simple to solve. you need your event listener run only once. there are some methods in javascript for doing that:

1. once option: addEventListener() have a third argument which can be an option object (with multiple properites) or use capture. for running the event listener only once we can use an option object with one property named once. it takes boolean values for example :

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // onClick code

}, {once : true});
```

2. Removing the event listener once the event is fired: we can remove the even listener right after first run for example :

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
function onClick(event){
   btn.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
   console.log("Event fired once, no more click will be handled");
}
btn.addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

*** UPDATE BY @PhilN ***

@CyrusKabir's answer is correct with regard to throttling the event click.  What is missing is a state check to know whether the camera should begin or continue animating.  We're missing a state variable to tell us if the button has *ever* been clicked.

In a common outer scope to the handler and `animate()`, we'll create a state boolean.

`let animatingCamera = false;`

So `animatingCamera` starts out `false`, meaning the button has not been clicked.  Inside of the `click` handler, we'll switch that state to `true`, and then let the handler unwire itself.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    animatingCamera = true;

}, {once : true});
```

Now, inside the `animate()` function, we'll wrap the assignment to `camera.position.x` inside a conditional that checks `animatingCamera`.   If `animatingCamera` is false, the button hasn't been clicked yet, and there's nothing to do, so the block exits.  If it's true, then the animate either is started or is running, so we'll let `animate()` update `camera.position.x`.

```
function animate() {
  ...
  if(animatingCamera){
    camera.position.x = ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @CyrusKabir. This doesn't solve my problem though. This isn't necessarily a javascript logic question, but is a three.js logic question. For right now, I don't need to remove the click handler but rather I need the three.js camera to move as if it was in the main animate() function but once the button is clicked rather then on page load.

Comment: Follow @CyrusKabir's first pattern, with these modifications.  In the outer scope, define `let animatingCamera = false;`.  Then in the `click` listener, add `animatingCamera = true;`.  Finally, in the `animate()` function, wrap your `camera.position.x` assignment inside of an `if(animatingCamera) { ... }`.  That state variable will start out `false`, it will get assigned `true` when the button is clicked, and the camera will only animate (and will continue to animate) once the button has been clicked and the state variable has been set `true`.

Comment: @PhilN. Your suggestions along with cyrus' methods worked! I appreciate the help from both of you.

Comment: Glad to help.  @CyrusKabir If you want to conform your answer with my comment, I'm sure brycall will accept it, and I'll vote it up.

Comment: @PhilN. I've never done it before since I haven't posted too much, but I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @PhilN thanks for completing my answer. for completing the answer, could you edit the post because I am not much familiar with three.js syntax in case of wrong edit or there is easier way to add your comment to my answer ?

Comment: Edits suggested, awaiting community approval as per SO